# Redirect slug, replace plus for dashes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, preg-replace, slug

I have a rewrite question. It drives me crazy. I created a new website in worpdress. I want to redirect old urls (that are in google) to the new urls. That works fine except for the following urls (there is a plus in the old url)

www.domain.com/slugname/this+is+a+slug

Has to be rewritten to:

www.domain.com/slugname/this-is-a-slug

How to replace the plus for a dash (.htacces? add_rewrite_rule?)

Sombody has example code?

I tried .htacces an add_rewrite_rule in worpdress, but im not smart enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to do it on an individual basis per URL then the following in your `.htaccess` file (it's important the file is spelt correctly) should work:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage$ http://www.example.org/newpage? [R=301,L]
```

So your example might be:

```
RewriteRule ^slugname/this+is+a+slug$ http://www.example.org/slugname/this-is-a-slug? [R=301,L]
```

The `R=301` part of the rule makes the redirect permanent, which I assume is the desired effect.  Removing this would make the redirect a `302`, which is known as temporary.

---

If you are looking to replace all `+` with `-` in the URL then you can use a generic statement:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction! But there are about a 1000 links that have that plus in the url so a generic solution would be great.

Comment: No problem, that should be even easier.  I've updated the answer with a second solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in WordPress called [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), that will allow you to redirect old links to new links. It takes a lot of hassle from trying to do it in the .htaccess. You can use regex on the plugin. 
Once installed the plugin can be found under the tools menu.

Comment: Oke, i installed it: The original url is somthing like: /blabla/7878/blabla+blalbal In the redirect module I use this /blabla/(.*d)/(.*?)+(.*?) and redirect it to /blabla/$2-$3 It does not work. What is my regex? What am i doing wrong